# If Background-Image url = then

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-image

What I am trying to do is change the `background-image` of a `div`, but only if the `background-image` url matches a certain url.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="test" style="background-image: url("/background1.png");">
```

Now what I've tried is this:

```
if ($('.test').css('background-image') === 'url(/background1.png)') {
    $('.test').css("background-image", "url(/background2.png)");
}
```

I know that the replace works, because if I remove the first line it updates all the background images for me, but I can't seem to get the first line to work.

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like this

```
 var bg = $(".test").css('background-image');
 bg = bg.replace('url("','').replace('")','');


 if (bg === '/background1.png') {
    $('.test').css("background-image", "url(/background2.png)");
 }
```

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bpv4Lggv/19/

Answer (score 0):

`.prop()` might get you where you need to be.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_prop.asp

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 0):

Use filter to get all the div with class test and matches background image (`url(/background1.png)`)

```
var filtered = $('.test').filter(function(test){
  return $(test).css('background-image') === 'url(/background1.png)';
});
//change filtered DOM only, with the new image background
$(filtered).css("background-image", "url(/background2.png)"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with JQuery but I think this was what you were asking for(in plain JavaScript)?

```
  if(element.style.backgroundImage == 'url("imagePathHere")'){
 // your code }
```

It's probably of little use now, but I was stuck trying to find a solution for a while until I console logged it and realized what my problem was, so maybe it can help someone else now